# How do I get a regulation changed in my state?

Tags: regulations, washington, cryptocurrency

I am looking to request a change in Washington States cryptocurrency regulations. Where would I start and at what point if any does a petition become important?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  This question might be better suited to [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com), as it's more about the law-making process than about the law itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about legal matters, but politics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, you cannot influence [the actual regulations](http://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?Cite=208-690). If you dislike the [authorized delegate advertising regulation](http://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=208-690-036), you would have to undermine the underlying statutory authority, [RCW 43.320.040](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=43.320.040) and [RCW 19.230.310](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=19.230.310). The legislature can change those laws, so write to the legislature; or, you can change the law via the initiative process which is where you get a petition going. The Dept. of Finance writes these rules in accordance with what the statutes say. The [laws were changed](http://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/biennium/2017-18/Pdf/Bills/Session%20Laws/Senate/5031-S.SL.pdf?cite=2017%20c%2030%20%C2%A7%201;) a year ago; it is not clear whether there are any unimplemented parts of the new law where the regulations haven't yet been written. DoF has a [page on rulemaking](https://dfi.wa.gov/agency-rulemaking) indicating recently-adopted rules and open rules. [This](https://dfi.wa.gov/rulemaking/municipal-securities-exemption) is a proposed rule pertaining to municipal securities and registration: there do not seem to be any open regulations regarding cryptocurrency.

Comment: You are assuming the regulations are in accordance with the legislation - regulations that aren't can be challenged by breaching them and then using their illegality as a defense in court.